# How to mount cd in single user mode?

Tags: mount, optical-drive, root, single-user

I don't see it listed under /dev. dmesg doesn't help. Apple diagnostics is missing from my computer and I believe there may be an issue with the hard drive so I was hoping to restore it from the install cd as per instructions elsewhere on the web.

I believe late 2007 iMac running 10.8.5

Just to be clear the iMac won't start up, not even in safe mode hence the single user mode reliance.

Comment: is there a 'single user mode' tag?

Comment: there is - added

Comment: Which iMac is it? Most machines will use AHT from the net if it can't be found on the machine itself - see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257

Comment: @Tetsujin if it shipped with OS X installation CD, that would be Snow Leopard - meaning that the firmware of the OP's machine doesn’t support networked AHT (with few exceptions). Nonetheless, more info is necessary and the tech specs would be useful.

Comment: Thanks @njboot - I wasn't sure when the transition occurred.

Comment: This iMac shipped with 10.6.

Comment: oops, its apple diagnostics I'm looking for. But all the same you're supposed to hold the 'D' key on start up for both programs, so its not like I just did the wrong thing.